# Spark execution error: spark-submit

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to execute a program from spark-shell with the below command

```
spark-submit --class com.aadharpoc.spark.UIDStats \ --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 \ --master yarn-client \ /home/cloudera/Desktop/aadhar_jar/Untitled.jar \ /home/cloudera/Desktop/UIDAI-ENR-DETAIL.csv
```

the following error prompoted

```
<console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'class' found.
       spark-submit --class com.aadharpoc.spark.UIDStats \ --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.5.0 \ --master local[*] \ /home/cloudera/Desktop/aadhar_jar/Untitled.jar \ /home/cloudera/Desktop/UIDAI-ENR-DETAIL.csv
```

Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not run the `spark-submit` from `scala REPL` or `spark-shell` You should run the `spark-submit` from normal `linux-shell` or `terminal`.

I hope this solves the issue.

Comment: Thanks @Shankar..I tried from terminal and it worked out

Comment: These are the import statements I have added                                    import org.apache.spark.{ SparkConf, SparkContext }
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext._                                      import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext                                                HiveContext is showing up with a strike through line. I don't understand what is the issue behind it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

spark-submit is a script used to submit a spark program and it is available in bin directory. It should be run from terminal and not from spark-shell.

In Windows, if env variable is updated till %SPARK_HOME%/bin then in window, just open command prompt and run spark-submit.

In Linux, SPARK_HOME must be in your .bashrc, then you can run from terminal else provide full qualified path like ....\spark-submit.sh